# simplereenroll for EST client using libCurl

Tags: c, linux, security, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to develop an EST client program in C using libcurl, to perform simpleenroll and simplereenroll. As of now, I was able to retrieve the certificate using **./well-known/est/simpleenroll.**, but I'm have a problem performing **./well-known/est/simplereenroll**

```
url = self.url_prefix + '/simplereenroll'
        auth = (self.username, self.password)
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/pkcs10'}
        content = est.request.post(url, csr, auth=auth, headers=headers,
            verify=self.implicit_trust_anchor_cert_path,
            cert=cert)
        pem = self.pkcs7_to_pem(content)
```

I was referring this python code where I could see the certificate being passed for simplereenroll operation. I don't know how to implement the same using libcurl.

Below mentioned is the portion of libcurl code which I'm using to perform the simpleenroll.

```
/*SIMPLEENROLL
 *
 */

if (res = curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL,"https://localhost:4443/.well-known/est/simpleenroll")!=CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"curl_easy_setopt() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));
        return 1;
    }
    struct curl_slist* slist = NULL;
    slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: application/pkcs10");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"estuser:estpwd")
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, CSR); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, CSR_LEN); 
    if((res = curl_easy_perform(curl))!=CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));
        return 1;       
    }
```

The above code will return a client certificate from server. Now I need to perform simplereenroll where I need to provide this certificate.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, client_key);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, client_cert);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 1L);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.